# Перегрузка функций

Tags: function-overloading, c++

Как перегрузить функцию в с++, не меняя её сигнатуры? Задали вопрос на собеседовании, теперь стало интересно, как такое возможно. Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Если вам на собеседовании задают такие вопросы, не идите туда работать. Их интересует не умение программировать, а знание странных трюков и далёких пыльных углов стандарта языка. Ищите компанию, где на собеседовании попросят написать код.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если сингнатура не изменяется, то и перегрузки нет. Это же логично. Но есть два варианта, что могли придумать вопрошающие.

1) если функцию поместить в другой namespace. Тогда можно будет вызывать разные версии.

```
void k(int x);
namespace my {
  void k(int x);
}

::k(1); // вызов первой
my::k(2); // вызов второй.
```

И конечно, можно добавить using namespace my; и вуаля:)

2) второй способ заключается в том, что в с++ нет методов. Точнее они есть, но называются функциями класса. А раз это функции, то можно сделать класс наследник и перегрузить в нем. Сигнатура при этом не будет изменяться.  Но нужно было уточнить, о какой функции думали они.

**UPD**
Новый, хитрый способ

Пусть есть себе функция

```
int func(int k, int m) { .... }
```

И нужно, что бы в новом месте была вызвана перегруженная версия. Для этого вначале напишем реализацию этой новой версии

```
int new_func(int k, int m) { .... }
```

И когда нужно будет вызывать, напишем так

```
#define my_func(a, b) func(a, b)
```

и пример вызова

```
func (1,1); // старая версия
#define func(a,b) my_func(a,b)
func(1,1); // новая версия, то есть по факту my_func
#undef func
func (1,1); // и снова старая
```

Да, этот способ требует "ручного выбора", но со стороны это выглядит вполне себе как перегрузка.

Comment: Я спросил про область видимости ф-ий, и они мне сказали, что находятся в одной области, я ответил сразу, что нельзя, но мне сказали, что можно, а как- сам думай(

Comment: тогда второй вариант.
но есть ещё один способ, дедовский. называется макросы. сейчас обновлю ответ.

Comment: Может быть они имели в виду преписку const в конце объявления метода.

Comment: спасибо, надеюсь, что нет какого-то ещё сверххитрого способа.

Comment: Мне кажется, технически трюк с макросом не считается перегрузкой. Думаю, они имели в виду определение метода (или функции, как вам угодно) в классе с такой же сигнатурой, как и в родительском классе, если она не виртуальная. Хотя кто их знает.

Comment: я не заметил, в общем, наверное все же имелось ввиду про const, всем спасибо, но на всякий случай буду все иметь ввиду.